# changing window.load scrollTop animation speed based on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scrolltop

I've setup my site to scroll past a mandatory header element by using a scrollTop to a certain div function. I specifically set it to scroll slow so that the user "knows the header is up there" but on subsequent pages, I'd rather it just start at that scrolled position.

I'm trying to use a simple if / else statement to grab the wordpress page (is_home) and set the animation to 1200, else set the animation to 0. I've even gone in and setup a custom field on the page of is_home and True. But it's still not working. Any ideas how to fix the if / else or suggestions for a better way to implement this?

```
if (is_home()) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#grey").offset().top
        }, 1200);
    });
} else {
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#grey").offset().top
        }, 0);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `if(is_home())` is a php statement from the WordPress API, which isn't available in JS. You could include different script calls based on this, but it's rather bad practice in my opinion.

Make sure the below is executed after your plugin, and jquery obviously. Good place might be after `wp_footer()`

```
<?php 
if (is_home()) { ?>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#grey").offset().top
        }, 1200);
    });
    </script>    
<?php } else { ?>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#grey").offset().top
        }, 0);
    });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yep. Goofy mistake on my part. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. By the way, I answered first and the above guy copied :(

Comment: Moved the checkmark but I can't upvote anybody. No rep.

Answer (score 0):

You are combining php and JavaScript together. [is_home](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)() is a PHP statement
You need to rewrite your code as below:

```
<?php
    if (is_home()) {
 ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#grey").offset().top
                }, 1200);
            });
        </script>
<?php 
    } else {
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#grey").offset().top
                }, 0);
            });
        </script>        
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

Also use `jQuery` instead of `$` to avoid conflict any other JavaScript libraries

Comment: Awesome. That worked great. I had to change (is_home()) to (is_front_page) but it was exactly what I needed. I didn't event think about php vs js. Thanks!